# How to I filter list options when typing on a input box?

Tags: javascript, html, input

In HTML, I have a input box and some unordered list items below it. When the user starts typing in the input box, I want the list item that is most relevant to move to the top, and have unrelevant items disappear. (Almost like an auto-complete form or a Google Search) How do I do this with just Javascript?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Write out some pseudo-code, thinking through the logic behind it, then convert it into actual code. Once you have some code you've tried, if you still can't figure it out, you can research what isn't working and if you still can't find an answer, then post a question here...

Answer (score 2):

Hi @blueWater can you try this once. it may solve your problem

resource from [link here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_filter_list)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>

<h2>My Phonebook</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

  

  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```